# Calling trace from class other than Page class

Tags: asp.net, trace

When I call `Trace.WriteLine()` from classes other than my page class, the output doesn't make it to my logs.  Calling the same function from my page class works just fine, though.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("")` for your tracing output to show up.